# Boot-repair not working after installing win10_20H2 after debian

Tags: dualboot, bootrepair

i've been running debian for quite a while, i wanted to install windows because i'll use it on classes, so i tried to make a bootable drive with win10_20H2 and Disk Image Mounter, with WoeUsb-ng and with Balena Etcher in all these cases the USB drive simply didn't appear on the UEFI menu of boot options like if i didn't plugged it in.

So with my sister's laptop which has dual-boot ubuntu and windows (dual-boot which i made) i used the windows media creation tool, now it worked, i choose it as boot, installed windows on the previously made partition allocated for it and proceed to repair grub with boot-repair on a live ubuntu.

I got an error, as i said i've done this before and i got errors with boot-repair but then grub works fine, but this time i rebooted and a grub2 shell poped out, i don't know how to proceed after this, please help me, thanks in advance.

Here is the boot info file generated by boot-repair: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1g6w9dbeOxoG3rN72SGLCUsXWgBpVqOU0/view?usp=sharing

Let me know if you need any extra information.